# Two Types of Screwdriver Rotary Switch Dials Available

Tags: switches

I was looking at some rotary trimmer switches:
http://www.grayhill.com/assets/1/7/DIP_Series_94H.pdf

And noticed that the flush screwdriver dial is available in two different designs for the same part.

[image]

The fact that the same part offers both (rather than some parts offering just one design and other parts offering only the other design) seems to imply that the dial design functionally matters somehow in some applications. But I can't think of a situation where it would actually matter. Has anyone come by a situation where it does?

Comment: I'm hard pressed to think of anything other than aesthetics... Some designs use dials/switches like these as customer facing inputs.

Comment: I bet a screwdriver can fit into the slot in the middle of each dial, and the slot points a different way on each one.

Comment: @Stiddily Yeah, I dunno. Maybe aesthetics really is worth the extra tooling cost.

Comment: We need a UXE in here stat! Although, user253751 brings up a good point, the A style does look much easier to turn with a screwdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a machine on the production line that sets them automatically to the correct preset you need to have the slot facing the right way.

Comment: Seems as more objective than any reason I can come up with.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Images from the datasheet.*

The A type seem to have a protruding shaft to take a knob. The arrow can be used when the knob is not present and as an assembly guide as to where to place the knob digit window.

The F type are flush.

---

No, this answer is not correct. Some of the A type are flat. I don't know.